# InnoDB Primary Key - Auto Increment vs Manual Sequence

Tags: innodb, sequence, auto-increment

I was thinking about the following situation:

A stock history table should be realized. The stockHistory references an item Table, so each modification of the stock from an item should be logged.

There are 2 possibilities:

```
    1) stockHistoryId -> AUTO_INCREMENT
       itemId         -> refers to the item table

    2) itemId         -> reference to the item table
       sequence       -> sequence, increments uniquely per itemId
```

Example for 2 would be:

```
    itemId sequence
    1      1
    1      2
    2      1
    2      2
    3      1
    3      2
    ...
```

If I understood correctly, the PRIMARY Key is used in InnoDb for storing on disk.

As such, if I use the first approach with an AUTO INCREMENT Key as primary key, there is a performancy penalty if you "look far in the future".

As, for example, the stockHistory might look like this:

```
stockHistoryId itemId
1              1
2              2
3              3
... (many other entries)
500000        1
.....
750000        1
```

so the itemId would be saved "fragmented" on the disk....

If I use the other approach, there would be no fragmentation, as everythings sorted by itemId on disk.

Am I completely wrong or is this correct? Having a hard time grasping all the fine details....

Comment: An index on `itemId` would take care of this -- no need to contort the schema over it, IMO.  And if your key auto-increments, you can already put the history in order by sorting by the primary key.  Or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, but If I use an auto increment key and sort by the auto increment, I do not have ONE itemId. I was thinking what is more efficient as the system basically wants only to "log" what stock has changed for "which" itemId. And If I understood the MySQL documentation regarding InnoDB file storage on disk, it should be more efficient to use ItemId as a primary key with a manually generated sequence instead of a auto increment key for all entries...

Comment: You're not going to have one itemId anyway, unless you use a `where` clause -- in which case, either way will work if you index that column.  And a manually-generated sequence is quite a bit harder to make reliable.  `max(sequence) + 1`, for example, breaks very easily in high-throughput scenarios.  Even having a table for sequences breaks all to hell unless you make all your transactions serializable, in which case your performance issues might be worse due to all the locking.